# Prevent squares from overlapping using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, css

I would simply like to prevent the random divs from overlapping. I have tried adding a margin, floating left, and adding a border. Nothing has worked thus far.

http://jsfiddle.net/QcUPk/2349/

```
(function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var num = 2;
    var percent = 10;
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': color,
        'border':num+'px'
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(1000, makeDiv).delay(4000).fadeOut(200, function(){
       $(this).remove();
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: You're using `position: absolute` and thus `margin` has no effect on the elements. You have to implement a collision detection.

Comment: `position: float` used with `float: left` will fill viewport with non-overlapping divs, but random positioning will be lost obviously. You could put more white divs for spacing, but effect won't be the same. For identical effect less overlaps, the only way seems to be KittMedia's suggestion of collision detection.

Comment: @StephenTafler Your jsfiddle code and the code given here is not same please edit .

Comment: @Stephen I like this effect thanks for posting

Comment: If you use collision detection remember you would have to store the position and divsize of all the divs which are displayed at a particular instance and this will change according to your `fadeIn` , `delay` and `fadeOut` values like for example for fadeIn `1000` , delay `4000` and fadeOut `200` , max 5 divs are displayed on the screen so you would have to store the position and divsize of last 5 divs that were generated everytime and then create the new one which don't overlap with any of those 5 divs.

Comment: I will research collision detection and post my findings here. Also, here is what I am trying to accomplish. This question is just a piece of my final solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726914/simultaneously-squares-on-pages-fading-in-and-out-with-javascript